# Javascript - Validate form if error found change form field background color to red

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Ive got a form, when the user clicks on a field the value clears, when the user clicks submit, AND an error is found the background color of the field should change to red.

**My problem**

I manage to  clear the value of the field when a user clicks it, and I managed to change the  color of the field to red when an error is found, BUT when the error is found when the user clicks submit **the background color only change to red for a split second and then the field value reapers again.**  Ive been battling away with this for the whole morning any help would be appreciated, code follows:

```
function validate(){
    //form validation
    var name=document.getElementById('name');
     if (name.value == null || name.value==""){
       name.style.backgroundColor="red";
     }  

<form id="enquire" method="post">
    <h2>Test Drive an Audi Today</h2>
    <input type="text"  value="Name" class="textbox" id="name" name="name" onclick="if(this.value=='Name') this.value='';" /><br />


<input type="submit" name="submit" class="butt" value="Send" onclick="validate()"  />
       <span class="buttonText">We'll Call you Back!</span>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="butt" value="Send" onclick="validate()"  />
       <span class="buttonText">We'll Call you Back!</span>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="butt" value="Send" onclick="return validate()"  />
       <span class="buttonText">We'll Call you Back!</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

The closing bracket of the function is missing.

```
function validate(){
    //form validation
    var name=document.getElementById('name');
     if (name.value == null || name.value==""){
       name.style.backgroundColor="red";
       return false;    // add this line
     }
}   // This was missing
```

Comment: I think OP had a typo error in the code that is shown here and not the actual code that was implemented

Comment: I don't think it is due to typo

Comment: @chris97ong sorry I should have mentioned the above code was only a snip of my code, the function is closed and I have a return false...still same problem